# I'm trying to import data to access from Excel and keep getting told it was unable to append all the data to the table

Tags: excel, ms-access

I need to get data from a .xslx file into an existing table in an access database. This is an older database (it's been in my company for ages, I don't know exactly how old it is) that I've recently migrated to a Windows 10 environment. When I attempt this, I get the following error message:

Microsoft Access was unable to append all the data to the table.

The contents of fields in 0 record(s) were deleted, and 0 record(s) were lost due to key violations.

- If data was deleted, the data you pasted or imported doesn't match the field data types or the FieldSize property in the destination table.
- If records were lost, either the records you pasted contain primary key values that already exist in the destination table, or they violate referential integrity rules for a relationship defined between tables.

The only key value in the access table is a generated ID number for each row. Things I have tried are:

- Importing the Excel spreadsheet into a new table, which works. I compared the datatypes in the new table to the datatypes in the old table, and they match.
- I have also gone through the excel spreadsheet and formatted each cell to match the access table datatypes.
- Reordered the columns in the old table to match the order output in the new table. This shouldn't matter, but I was desperate.

What might the actual problem be here?

Comment: Are you using `External Data > Import & Link > Excel`?

Comment: Yes, I am doing that, but I have to also go through the New Data Source menu on my ribbon, which is under Import & Link, and shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Not sure why that would be necessary, but anyway … Does the .xlsx file have column names in the first row of the sheet? If so, does one of those names match the name of the AutoNumber column in the table?

Comment: No, but the excel sheet is getting automatically generated by iSeries, getting information from our server. The AutoNumber column is named ID, and I don't think the ID column is being generated into the excel file on the older computers. I'll try to add one though to see if that's the issue.

Comment: It just created a subscript out of range error as soon as I hit import...

Comment: It appears that direct import from Excel into an existing table requires that the sheet have column names in the first row. You could either hack the .xlsx file to include those names or import into a separate table and then run an "Append Query" to insert the rows into the existing table.

Comment: The sheet does have names in the first row for all the other columns except the for the autonumber column in the existing table. This autonumber column is still being generated in the new table that I created by importing to a new table so I'm not sure if that would be causing the issue.

Comment: Wait I just noticed that when I'm inspecting the xlsx file in the import spreadsheet wizard, some of the columns are just full of junk data that definitely aren't there when I'm viewing it through excel.

Comment: Does the .xlsx file have any hidden columns?